# ImporperlyConfigured Django Exception in stand-alone package

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I have made an egg from django (1.6) project (lets say `pialon`) with application (`web_interface_app`).
And I have Scrapy project, with virtualenv. I install django app via `pip install /path/to/egg.tar.gz`

All I want to do is - to use Django ORM in Scrapy pipeline. Basically, I do something like this:

pipelines.py:

```
from pialon.web_interface_app import models
models.Posts.objects.all()
```

But this thorws me an error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Any ideas how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Django's ORM without using the full Django suite, then you need to configure it before you run.

You can create a django settings file and point the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable to it, or you can call `settings.configure`.

The [documentation explains this here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#using-settings-without-setting-django-settings-module). It's pretty straightforward:

```
from django.conf import settings

settings.configure(DEBUG=True, ONE_SETTING=1, ANOTHER_SETTING=2, SOME_SETTING=3)
```

Note that if you're only interested in default settings, you probably don't actually need to pass any settings in there.